# Getting the non-matching part between two strings in TCL

Tags: string, tcl

I have two strings in variables where the left part of the string is always same. I need to get the rightmost part:

```
set cwd "/this/is/my/path"
set full_file "/this/is/my/path/test.tcl"
```

I need the following:

```
"/test.tcl"
```

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution for any two strings, or are you specifically targeting file paths?

Answer (score 1):

Tcl has excellent path manipulation functions, they may be helpful:

```
set tail [file tail $full_file]
```

Note that this will not include the leading /.

If your path may contain other elements past the `$cwd`, you can use
a regular expression to remove the prefix:

```
regsub $cwd $full_file {} tail
puts $tail
```

You have to be careful with this, if `$cwd` contains any special 
characters that the regular expression recognizes, it will fail
or get strange results.  In which case you will need a procedure 
to escape the special characters:

```
proc escapeRegex { val } {
  regsub -all {([?*.+^${}()\\\[\]"])} $val {\\\1} val
  return $val
}
regsub [escapeRegex $cwd] $full_file {} tail
puts $tail
```

( This code does not handle leading `~` characters ).

Comment: The `escapeRegex` regex can be simpler: `regsub -all {[^\w\s]} $val {\\&}` will escape any non-word, non-space characters. And use `&` in the replacement to use the matching text. Leave off the trailing varname and the new text is returned, so you don't even need the return statement.

Comment: OR, use the [regex metasyntax](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M82) to specify the pattern as literal text. If `set x {foo.bar.*.baz}; set pattern {.*}` then compare `regsub $pattern $x {--}` to `regsub "(?q)$pattern" $x {--}`

Comment: @glennjackman; I was looking for that `(?q)`, but did not find it easily.  That would be the best way.

Comment: But it fails to compile: "^(?q)/home/bll/stuff/"

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

```
% set cwd "/this/is/my/path"
% set full_file "/this/is/my/path/test.tcl"

% string map [list $cwd ""] $full_file
/test.tcl

% string range $full_file [string length $cwd] end
/test.tcl
```

The 2nd one does not verify they are the same though.
And the 1st one does not specify to match at the start of the string.

Both of these caveats can be satisfied with:

```
if {[string match "${cwd}*" $full_file]} { ... }
```

Comment: The `string equal` command takes a `-length` option, which would make for a safer comparison than `string match` (which has some metacharacters that can surprise). Or you can use `string first` and check if that finds at the start of the string.